# GPO - Software Restriction Policies - add exception

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

Windows Server 2012 R2 and GPO. I wanted to increase security so I blocked 
`%AppData%\*.exe` and `%AppData%\*\*.exe`

Spotify stopped working of course. I created another rule `%AppData%\Roaming\Spotify\Spotify.exe`, `%AppData%\Roaming\Spotify\SpotifyLauncher.exe` and set up to `Unrestricted`.

But still I receive error: *This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator.*

Any suggestions how can I unblock selected programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh stupid me.

Where does *%AppData%* lead? To *C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming* so instead `%AppData%\Roaming\Spotify\Spotify.exe` there should be `%AppData%\Spotify\Spotify.exe`

Also, for future use. I have to add something from *AppData\Local* so I can't use `%AppData%\Local`, but `%ProfilePath%\Appdata\Local` or just `%LocalAppData%`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link which is very detailed.
Sounds like setting a white-list would be helpful for you.

https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/57422-deploying-a-whitelist-software-restriction-policy-to-prevent-cryptolocker-and-more

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Ironic posting about not using a link by posting a link...